# Make content inside Button responsive in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have vertical navigation bar. Each button of the navigation has it's own image and text. For now the image has static height set to `Height="50"`and text has the default value. When I resize the window the buttons grow responsive but the content inside keeps the same size.
This is how it look right now:
https://gyazo.com/48cff48437b66f462dccd23639dd59ac (GIF)

My XAML code:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <UniformGrid Background="DodgerBlue" Grid.Column="1" Columns="1">

      <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="DodgerBlue">
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="Icons/home-5-xxl.png" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">Home</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>

      <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="DodgerBlue">
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="Icons/search-3-xxl.png" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">Search</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>

      <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="DodgerBlue">
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="Icons/twitter-xxl.png" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">Twitter</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>

      <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="DodgerBlue">
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="Icons/chat-4-xxl.png" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">Chat</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>

    </UniformGrid>
  </Grid>
```

How could i make content inside the Buttons responsive and grow when the button grows in XAML WPF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779564/resize-image-in-wpf)

Comment: @AmittaiShapira I am asking for a solution in the XAML code and not in the code-behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Viewbox` as shown [here](https://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html).

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
   <Button ... />
</Viewbox>
```